# Kotlin: When extension function hides the class default implementation?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm trying to figure out when overriding an existing class function, with an extension function of the same signature - will take effect?

Here is my sample code:

```
fun String.toUpperCase(): String = "ext. function impl."

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println("Hello".toUpperCase()) // ext. function impl.

    println(MyClass().toUpperCase()) // class impl.

}

class MyClass {
    fun toUpperCase() : String {
        return "class impl."
    }
}

fun MyClass.toUpperCase() : String {
    return "ext. function impl."
}
```

So:

- What are the rules? when each will be called?
- How can I override this decision? is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically) (emphasis *not* mine):

> If a class has a member function, and an extension function is defined which has the same receiver type, the same name and is applicable to given arguments, the **member always wins**.

The reason your string example works is because the library-provided `String.toUpperCase()` is *already* an extension function, not a member function.  The docs don't state what happens here, but seems reasonable to assume that a local extension wins.

---

I don't imagine there's any way to alter this behaviour.  And that's  probably for the best, as it would violate the principle of least astonishment in many cases (i.e. behaviour that's difficult to understand).

Comment: This behavior is actually altered in a few places in `kotlin-stdlib` (e.g. [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Maps.kt#L133)), but that's done with `kotlin.internal.HidesMembers`, which is, evidently, an internal tool and is not available for third-party code. And that's for good.